# How does the exponential in the Fourier Transform affect its accuracy?

Tags: fourier-analysis, exponential-function, fourier-transform

I know that the length of the time interval of a function affects the accuracy of its Fourier Transform. So when we take a longer interval of a function, it is easier to distinguish between the different root frequencies.

I have already explained it this way in my paper. However, when applying to an example (transform of the same function, once over 5 seconds and the other time over 30 seconds):

$$ \hat{j}_5(f)=\int_{0}^{5} (\sin(4\pi t)+\sin(4.2\pi t))e^{-2\pi ift} \,dx=\frac{e^{-10\pi if}-1}{\pi f^2-4\pi}-\frac{1.05\left(e^{-10\pi if}+1\right)}{\pi f^2-4.41\pi} $$
$$ \hat{j}_{30}(f)=\int_{0}^{30} (\sin(4\pi t)+\sin(4.2\pi t))e^{-2\pi ift} \,dx=\frac{e^{-60\pi if}-1}{\pi f^2-4\pi}-\frac{1.05\left(e^{-60\pi if}+1\right)}{\pi f^2-4.41\pi} $$

I was interested to see that the only difference in the final equations was the exponential term. In $ \hat{j}_5(f) $ it is $ e^{-10\pi if} $ and in $ \hat{j}_{30}(f) $ it is $ e^{-60\pi if} $. The graph of $ \hat{j}_{30}(f) $ has a higher density of maxima and minima, and that appears to be the reason the frequencies 2Hz and 2.1Hz can be distinguished.

[image]     Values of $ \hat{j}_5(f) $

[image]     Values of $ \hat{j}_{30}(f) $

However, I want to explain this referring to the difference in exponential term. What is a valid explanation for it?

Comment: The FT of the sine function is the sum of Dirac Deltas.  Dirac Deltas are distributions, not functions.  By truncating, the interval, you have tacitly taken the Fourier transform of the product of the sine function and a rectangular function.  The result is the convolution of the Dirac Deltas and a Sinc function.  This is equivalent to the sum of nascent Dirac Deltas.

Comment: @MarkViola I've self-studied the FT lightly but I don't know what Dirac Deltas are. Should I learn this and explain the answer this way, or is there a simpler way to explain?

Comment: Note that the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \sin(2\pi f_0 t) e^{i2\pi ft}\,dt$ does not exist.  However, the Fourier transform of $\sin(t)$ does exist as a Tempered Distribution and is equal to $\frac1{2i}(\delta(f+f_0)-\delta(f-f_0))$, where $\delta$ is the DIrac Delta.  We can heuristically view the Dirac Delta as a pulse of infinitesimal width, and infinite amplitude, such that the area the pulse is $1$.

Comment: Understood. In my paper, I present the example the same way as above, without mentioning the infinity limits. This is high school so FT is already quite advanced and such depth isn't needed. Also, thanks for the quick introduction—I will look further into Dirac Delta.